# What does pre-warming and pre-fetching provide in chromecustomTabs?

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

What does this pre-warming pre fetching play the role in chromecustomTabs? I was told on Google that these could help urls to get loaded faster! However, did the warm-up URL readlly gets content of the page ? If

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from this article: https://medium.com/google-developers/best-practices-for-custom-tabs-5700e55143ee the warm-up saves 700ms by making sure the Chrome process is ready in advance.

The other improvements are:

- DNS prefetching
- pre-rendering the page

The page still takes as long to load as normal but this happens in the background so the user isn't aware of it.

Comment: Will pre-rendering really load the JavaScript in the page?

Comment: Yes as described here: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/prerender

Comment: I quote one sentence from the article, is this available in android?
"Prerenders are destroyed if not used within 5 minutes.  The source page can cancel the prerender earlier if desired."